# What is the proper use of localCheckpoint()

Tags: pyspark

I am in need of using `localCheckpoint()` to resize shuffle partitions, but I am unsure how to use it properly. I searched through Github as well as Stackoverflow and found effectively everyone repeating this block of code (with no further context, situation, reasoning, etc) which is from this databricks presentation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=daXEp4HmS-E

```
df.localCheckpoint(...).repartition(n).write(...)
```

How do I use this properly? For instance, do I:

```
df = df.localCheckpoint()
```

or

```
df.localCheckpoint()
```

Under what conditions would I repartition? Is specifying the write necessary?

Let's say I have specified my number of shuffle partitions like so:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 1200);

# bunch of work here

# local checkpoint here
```

But I have more work to do, but at a different shuffle scale, so then can I set my shuffle partitions again, like so?

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 400);

# more work here

# local checkpoint again
```

Finally, write to disk:

```
df.coalesce(n).write....
```

How should `localCheckpoint()` be used in work that we have to chain together at different shuffle scales?

Also, how can I use two `localCheckpoint()` operations? If I run one `localCheckpoint()` on `df` but then run another on `df2`; when I return to yet another `localCheckpoint()` on `df`, I get:

`Checkpoint block rdd_322_17 not found! Either the executor that originally checkpointed this partition is no longer alive, or the original RDD is unpersisted`

Comment: you need to use `df = df.localCheckpoint()` because this function returns a new dataframe. If you  do `df.localCheckpoint()` - it will do the checkpoint, but existing dataframe will stay the same, and you just spend resources on checkpointing without benefit